# PHPMailer Duplicate Emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Inconsistent duplicate emails occurring when using php mailer.

Function that mails:

```
function SendEmail($to,$cc,$bcc,$subject,$body) {
    require( GetPHPMailPath() );
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $addresses = explode(',', $to);
    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
        $mail->AddAddress($address);
    }
    if($cc!='') {
        $mail->addCustomHeader("CC: " . $cc);
    }
    if($bcc!=''){
        $mail->addCustomHeader("BCC: " . $bcc);
    }
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 587;   
    $mail->Username = "email@email.com"; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
    $webmaster_email = "email"; //Reply to this email ID
    $name=$email;
    $mail->From = $webmaster_email;
    $mail->FromName = "Service";
    $mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    return $mail->Send();
}
```

How I am calling the function:

```
echo SendEmail($toAddress,$ccAddress,$bccAddress,$subject,$body);
```

The really odd part about this whole ordeal is that it is inconsistent which means there may be nothing wrong with the code but the connection to gmail?

Any ideas maybe its a `php.ini` problem?

Comment: PHPMailer only sends one message at a time, so duplicate messages usually means you've got browser requests that you don't know about. These are most often caused by browser plugins that do invisible reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a lag related issue.

PHPMailer functioned properly. User was sending duplicate requests. Fixed by adding comparison check with MySQL database records.